# java.util.Map.Entry versus Entry

Tags: java

These two `for` statements are equivalent.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry: map.entrySet())
    ;

for (Entry<String, Double> entry: map.entrySet())
    ;
```

Often programmers write `Map.Entry` rather than `Entry` yet they can be equivalent. Furthermore the interface is described as [Map.Entry at this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) and not simply `Entry`.

The enclosing `Map` interface even refers to `Map.Entry` in its own documentation on this [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Of course the verbose way avoids ambiguity but what specific ambiguity are people trying to avoid? In other words, what are the other commonly used classes identified by `Entry` that can be pointed to in order to justify this practice?

Comment: It might just be an issue of whether you want to have the extra import for `Map.Entry`.  I seem to recall seeing both versions used commonly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other **commonly** used `Entry` class inside the **Java standard library**. Choosing to import `Map.Entry` in order to use `Entry` directly should be sufficient in most applications.

So besides the issue to uniquely identify a class it is purely cosmetic and some kind of **personal preference**.

I personally see the usage of `Entry` more frequently but I have also seen the other variant. Again, it is just a personal preference and there is no reason why you would **need** to do this.

---

Also keep in mind that many people use IDEs and they often automate the import process. So the reason that a programmer specificly uses this or that version could also be that his IDE simply decided for that version. For example my *Eclipse* tends to use the most closest import statement, so it will choose to import `Map.Entry` and thus I use just `Entry` inside the code.

---

Just for the record, here is a list of `Entry` classes my *standard Java* contains:

[image: Entry classes in the standard Java]

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is cosmetic. Both refer to the same class, which can be found under the package `java.util.Map` as an `Entry` class. The difference is merely how you wish to write it.

You could do

```
for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, Double> entry: map.entrySet())
```

with no imports if you wanted to as well, but if you have many entries to deal with in your class you'll be writing that many times, which is less readable.

Edit:

As a note, if you use many classes from a package `foo` and you choose to use class `Test` under `foo.bar`, your IDE may sometimes directly import it as `bar.Test` and keep the import `foo.*`. You can always choose to manually import `foo.bar` And use it as `Test` directly, or go with the bar prefix whenever you write your type.

Comment: To wrap it up: The only reason is to help the compiler find the class. As long as it is uniquely identified by the currently used expression it is purely *cosmetic*. But I think OP did already know that because he is just asking for reasons why to describe it more closer if it is already uniquely identified.

Comment: Does this post answer *what specific ambiguity are people trying to avoid? In other words, what are the other commonly used classes identified by Entry that can be pointed to in order to justify this practice?* ?

Comment: The question is whether importing `Map.Entry` and using `Entry` is different from importing `Map` and using `Map.Entry`. If the issue is distinguishing between other `Entry` classes, then users will need to make a note of either importing from the proper package or writing the full classname as your type. The main point is that either way works

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes, I feel it does.  The first sentence says it all - the only difference is cosmetic.  This answer is correct.